# Water reading. Subtract latest reading from previous based on dates selected

Tags: mysql

I have a table of water readings.  I need to know how much was consumed by each property based on 2 given dates.

Below is how my data looks like.

[image: water readings]

How can I create a mysql query which will

1. ask what dates (say between 08/16/2021 and 08/12/2021) to get the difference in readings
2. compute the difference
3. enter results in a new column "consumed between 8/12 and 8/16".

I am very new with mysql and your assistance is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.  And more explanation too.  What if there are no readings on those dates?

Comment: Queries do not ask for user inputs. Programs do.

Comment: Aside from your question needing more detail (such as what you've tried so far, and what issues you're having): please provide formatted text instead of images of text for things like code, queries, and sample data. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

In this query, you can replace your start and end dates with your application variables or stored procedure parameters.

Find my step-by-step queries here -> [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9bf20fe9f0b39366a0f0e088a867e35c)

Try this -

```
set @v_start_date = '2021-08-12';
set @v_end_date = '2021-08-16';

SELECT
    wr_start_table.Unit_No,
    wr_start_table.Date,
    wr_start_table.Reading,
    wr_end_table.Date,
    wr_end_table.Reading,
    wr_end_table.Reading - wr_start_table.Reading AS difference_in_reading
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        wr_start_unit.*
    FROM
        water_reading wr_start_unit
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            wr.Unit_No,
            min(wr.Date) AS start_date
        FROM
            water_reading wr
        WHERE
            wr.Date >= @v_start_date
        GROUP BY
            wr.Unit_No) AS wr_start ON
        wr_start.Unit_No = wr_start_unit.Unit_No
        AND wr_start.start_date = wr_start_unit.Date) AS wr_start_table,
    (
    SELECT
        wr_end_unit.*
    FROM
        water_reading wr_end_unit
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            wr.Unit_No,
            max(wr.Date) AS end_date
        FROM
            water_reading wr
        WHERE
            wr.Date <= @v_end_date
        GROUP BY
            wr.Unit_No) AS wr_end ON
        wr_end.Unit_No = wr_end_unit.Unit_No
        AND wr_end.end_date = wr_end_unit.Date) AS wr_end_table
WHERE
    wr_start_table.Unit_No = wr_end_table.Unit_No;
```